# How to triangulate polygons in Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, triangulation, boost-polygon

What is the best way to triangulate a polygon with Boost?

I use [Boost.polygon](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm).

My current algorithm:

1. Compute a voronoï diagram from my polygon vertices.
2. Create one directed polygon-edge for each cell-edge (this will create two directed polygon edge per cell-edge)
3. Iterate over all created edges to create triangles (not trivial)

Any better solution?

Edit: I just realized that it is probably possible to walk through the cells in a special way to create the triangles directly (3 neighbor cells create a triangle).

Comment: Just to be clear: are these polygons convex?

Comment: Not necessarily, and they can have holes ; but they are not complex.

Answer (score 8):

The main idea is to iterate through the Voronoi vertices, and create a triangle from the generating points of each cell incident on the Voronoi vertex. In the case of degenerate vertex with degree > 3 then you'll need to generate more than one triangle, but that is easily done using a triangle fan.

Using Boost Polygon:

```
#include "boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp"

std::vector<Point> vertices;
// add your input vertices

boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<double> vd;
boost::polygon::construct_voronoi(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), &vd);

for (const auto& vertex: vd.vertices()) {
    std::vector<Point> triangle;
    auto edge = vertex.incident_edge();
    do {
        auto cell = edge->cell();
        assert(cell->contains_point());

        triangle.push_back(vertices[cell->source_index()]);
        if (triangle.size() == 3) {
            // process output triangles
            std::cout << "Got triangle:" << triangle << std::endl;
            triangle.erase(triangle.begin() + 1);
        }

        edge = edge->rot_next();
    } while (edge != vertex.incident_edge());
}
```

See also [How to triangulate from a Voronoï diagram?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/how-to-triangulate-from-a-vorono%C3%AF-diagram) for more background on the problem.

Comment: For non-convex polygons (and possibly polygons with holes), it is needed to check whether the centerpoint of the found triangle lies inside the polygon. Use `boost::polygon::contains()` for the check near `// process output triangles``.