# Delaunay from Voronoi with boost: missing triangle with non-integral point coordinates

Tags: c++, boost, voronoi, delaunay, boost-polygon

Following this two resources:

- [Boost basic tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/polygon/example/voronoi_basic_tutorial.cpp)
- [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342038/how-to-triangulate-polygons-in-boost)

I wrote a Delaunay triangulation with `boost`. It works fine if the points coordinates are integral (I generated several random tests and I did not observed error). However if the points are non integral I found many incorrect triangulations with missing edges or wrong edges.

For example this image has been build with rounded value and is correct (see code below)

[image]

But this image as been build with raw values and is incorrect (see code below)

[image]

This code reproduce this two examples (without the display).

```
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
using boost::polygon::voronoi_builder;
using boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram;

struct Point
{
  double a;
  double b;
  Point(double x, double y) : a(x), b(y) {}
};

namespace boost
{
  namespace polygon
  {
    template <>
    struct geometry_concept<Point>
    {
      typedef point_concept type;
    };

    template <>
    struct point_traits<Point>
    {
      typedef double coordinate_type;

      static inline coordinate_type get(const Point& point, orientation_2d orient)
      {
        return (orient == HORIZONTAL) ? point.a : point.b;
      }
    };
  }  // polygon
}  // boost

int main()
{ 

 std::vector<double> xx = {8.45619987, 9.96573889, 0.26574428, 7.63918524, 8.15187618, 0.09100718};
 std::vector<double> yy = {9.2452883, 7.0843455, 0.4811701, 3.1193826, 5.1336435, 5.5368374};

 // std::vector<double> xx = {8, 10, 0, 8, 8, 0};
 // std::vector<double> yy = {9, 7, 0, 3, 5, 6};

  std::vector<Point> points;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < xx.size() ; i++)
  {
    points.push_back(Point(xx[i], yy[i]));
  }

  // Construction of the Voronoi Diagram.
  voronoi_diagram<double> vd;
  construct_voronoi(points.begin(), points.end(), &vd);

  for (const auto& vertex: vd.vertices())
  {
    std::vector<Point> triangle;
    auto edge = vertex.incident_edge();
    do
    {
      auto cell = edge->cell();
      assert(cell->contains_point());

      triangle.push_back(points[cell->source_index()]);
      if (triangle.size() == 3)
      {   
        // process output triangles
        std::cout << "Got triangle: (" << triangle[0].a << " " << triangle[0].b << ") (" << triangle[1].a << " " << triangle[1].b << ") (" << triangle[2].a << " " << triangle[2].b << ")" << std::endl;
        triangle.erase(triangle.begin() + 1);
      }

      edge = edge->rot_next();
    } while (edge != vertex.incident_edge());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might be a bug in the boost library. Some tickets in their bugtracker look similar to your problem: [Missing edges in Voronoi Diagram](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/12707) and [polygon/voronoi missing edges](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/12067)

Comment: Probably. Bad new because these bug reports are respectively one year and a half and two years old...

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal"?

Comment: Computational geometry with floating point numbers is very hard. Don't expect boost to do it for you. Use integral or rational coordinates.

Comment: Can you show us what the input data should look like? Because any way I look at the input (even the integer input) it looks like invalid polygons anyway.

Comment: @MarcGlisse right, it is a problem with my English actually. I meant integral. Thanks

Comment: @sehe the input data really look like the one in the code.

Comment: @JRR No no. Not what the NUMBERS look like. What would a corresponding shape look like? I've seen the numbers. And neither me, nor the software I used can figure out a valid polygon from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It works fine if the points coordinates are not decimal

After playing around with your sample I suddenly realized you didn't mean "when the coordinates are not decimal". You meant "integral". Big difference.

[Documentation: Point Concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_coordinate_concept.htm)

> The coordinate type is expected to be integral

and

> Floating point coordinate types are not supported by all the algorithms and generally not suitable for use with the library at present.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I understood digging in the doc (especially the `voronoi_builder`. Actually I only need a 2 digits accuracy so I multiplied the input by 100 and I transtyped to integers.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked a lot more at your input data. There's only two valid polygons I can "imagine" from that:

1. Ring { {0,0}, {8, 3}, {10, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 6}, }
   [image]
2. Ring { {0,0}, {8, 3}, {8, 5}, {10, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 6}, }
   [image]

Let's define them in code:

```
Ring const inputs[] = {
            Ring { {0,0}, {8, 3}, {10, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 6}, }, // {0, 0},
            Ring { {0,0}, {8, 3}, {8, 5}, {10, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 6}, } // {0, 0},
        };
```

> The closing points commented out are in case you have a polygon model that requires the polygon be closed.
>
> In this case, I've opted fro Boost Geometries polygon model, and parameterized it to be not-closed:
>
> ```
> static constexpr bool closed_polygons = false;
> using bgPoly  = bgm::polygon<Point, false, closed_polygons>;
> using bgMulti = bgm::multi_polygon<bgPoly>;
> using Ring    = bgPoly::ring_type;
> ```

### Let's do the tests

1. To create the test-cases that are not using integral numbers, let's transform the polygon by shifting it from (0,0) to (1,1) and also scaling every dimension by a factor of π.
2. let's also check for input validity (and optionally attempt to correct for errors):

   ```
   template <typename G> void validate(std::string name, G& geom) {
       std::cout << name << ": " << bg::wkt(geom) << "\n";

       std::string reason;
       if (!bg::is_valid(geom, reason)) {
           std::cout << name << ": " << reason << "\n";

           bg::correct(geom);

           std::cout << bg::wkt(geom) << "\n";
           if (!bg::is_valid(geom, reason)) {
               std::cout << name << " corrected: " << reason << "\n";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, let's save some SVG visualizations of the input and triangulations

### Demo Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52285a0e6df47210)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/polygon/voronoi.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using boost::polygon::voronoi_builder;
using boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram;

struct Point
{
    double a;
    double b;
    Point(double x = 0, double y = 0) : a(x), b(y) {}
};

namespace boost { namespace polygon {
    template <> struct geometry_concept<Point> { typedef point_concept type; };

    template <> struct point_traits<Point> {
        typedef double coordinate_type;

        static inline coordinate_type get(const Point& point, orientation_2d orient) {
            return (orient == HORIZONTAL) ? point.a : point.b;
        }
    };
} }

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/convex_hull.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/strategies/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = bg::model;
namespace bgs = bg::strategy;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Point, double, bg::cs::cartesian, a, b)

static constexpr bool closed_polygons = false;
using bgPoly  = bgm::polygon<Point, false, closed_polygons>;
using bgMulti = bgm::multi_polygon<bgPoly>;
using Ring    = bgPoly::ring_type;

template <typename G> void validate(std::string name, G& geom) {
    std::cout << name << ": " << bg::wkt(geom) << "\n";

    std::string reason;
    if (!bg::is_valid(geom, reason)) {
        std::cout << name << ": " << reason << "\n";

        bg::correct(geom);

        std::cout << bg::wkt(geom) << "\n";
        if (!bg::is_valid(geom, reason)) {
            std::cout << name << " corrected: " << reason << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;

    Ring const inputs[] = {
                Ring { {0,0}, {8, 3}, {10, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 6}, }, // {0, 0},
                Ring { {0,0}, {8, 3}, {8, 5}, {10, 7}, {8, 9}, {0, 6}, } // {0, 0},
            };

    bgs::transform::matrix_transformer<double, 2, 2> const transformations[] = {
            { 1,    0,    0, // identity transformation
              0,    1,    0,
              0,    0,    1 },
            { M_PI, 0,    1, // just to get nice non-integral numbers everywhere
              0,    M_PI, 1, // shift to (1,1) and scale everything by π
              0,    0,    1 },
            };

    for (auto transformation : transformations) {
        for (auto input : inputs) {
            validate("Input", input);

            Ring transformed_input;
            bg::transform(input, transformed_input, transformation);

            validate("transformed_input", transformed_input);

            // Construction of the Voronoi Diagram.
            voronoi_diagram<double> vd;
            construct_voronoi(transformed_input.begin(), transformed_input.end(), &vd);

            bgMulti out;
            Ring triangle;

            for (const auto& vertex: vd.vertices()) {
                triangle.clear();
                for(auto edge = vertex.incident_edge(); triangle.empty() || edge != vertex.incident_edge(); edge = edge->rot_next()) {
                    triangle.push_back(transformed_input[edge->cell()->source_index()]);

                    if (triangle.size() == 3) {

#if 0
                        std::cout << " -- found \n";
                        bgPoly t{triangle};
                        validate("Triangle", t);
                        out.push_back(t);
#else
                        out.push_back({ triangle });
#endif

                        triangle.erase(triangle.begin() + 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            std::cout << "Out " << bg::wkt(out) << "\n";
            {
                std::ofstream svg("/tmp/svg" + std::to_string(++count) + ".svg");
                boost::geometry::svg_mapper<Point> mapper(svg, 600, 600);

                mapper.add(out);
                mapper.map(out, R"(fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(153,204,0);stroke-dasharray=5,5;stroke-width:2)");

                mapper.add(transformed_input);
                mapper.map(transformed_input, R"(fill-opacity:0.1;fill:rgb(204,153,0);stroke:red;stroke-width:3)");
            }
        } // inputs
    } // transformations
}
```

The output:

```
Input: POLYGON((0 0,8 3,10 7,8 9,0 6))
transformed_input: POLYGON((0 0,8 3,10 7,8 9,0 6))
Out MULTIPOLYGON(((0 6,0 0,8 3,0 6)),((8 9,0 6,8 3,8 9)),((10 7,8 9,8 3,10 7)))
Input: POLYGON((0 0,8 3,8 5,10 7,8 9,0 6))
transformed_input: POLYGON((0 0,8 3,8 5,10 7,8 9,0 6))
Out MULTIPOLYGON(((0 6,0 0,8 3,0 6)),((8 5,0 6,8 3,8 5)),((8 9,0 6,8 5,8 9)),((8 9,8 5,10 7,8 9)),((10 7,8 5,8 3,10 7)))
Input: POLYGON((0 0,8 3,10 7,8 9,0 6))
transformed_input: POLYGON((1 1,26.1327 10.4248,32.4159 22.9911,26.1327 29.2743,1 19.8496))
Out MULTIPOLYGON(((1 19.8496,1 1,26.1327 10.4248,1 19.8496)),((26.1327 29.2743,1 19.8496,26.1327 10.4248,26.1327 29.2743)),((32.4159 22.9911,26.1327 29.2743,26.1327 10.4248,32.4159 22.9911)))
Input: POLYGON((0 0,8 3,8 5,10 7,8 9,0 6))
transformed_input: POLYGON((1 1,26.1327 10.4248,26.1327 16.708,32.4159 22.9911,26.1327 29.2743,1 19.8496))
Out MULTIPOLYGON(((1 19.8496,1 1,26.1327 10.4248,1 19.8496)),((26.1327 16.708,1 19.8496,26.1327 10.4248,26.1327 16.708)),((26.1327 29.2743,1 19.8496,26.1327 16.708,26.1327 29.2743)),((26.1327 29.2743,26.1327 16.708,32.4159 22.9911,26.1327 29.2743)),((32.4159 22.9911,26.1327 16.708,26.1327 10.4248,32.4159 22.9911)))
```

And the corresponding SVG files:

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eGtSwlf has the svg renders in 150dpi detail, SVGs [in the live Coliru output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52285a0e6df47210)

Comment: Scaling [down by 100x](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e257ec975bad7d) does run into the problems, leaving the output empty https://imgur.com/a/akTzxmM

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when the points are too small, like (0.411, 0.633), (0.142, 0.453), etc.

So I enlarge the points with `point.x * 100, point.y * 100`, and then the boost::polygon::voronoi works well, maybe this is due to the floating precision.