# Boost. Triangulation from arbitrary set of points

Tags: c++, boost, triangulation

Is it possible to triangulate an arbitrary set of points(double) using boost?

I know about CGAL, but I can't use it because of the license.

I found this [Delaunay from Voronoi with boost: missing triangle with non-integral point coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657847/delaunay-from-voronoi-with-boost-missing-triangle-with-non-integral-point-coord), it means I can't use boost?